# Setting Default "Character Set" in new projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I wanted set my new projects in Visual Studio (2010) to have the "Character Set" to be set to "Not Set" instead of the current default of "Unicode".

The setting I am referring to is normally located under "Configuration Properties" > "General" but I am unable to find a setting to affect this globally or for new files.

Is there a way to do this?